# Connection between the $S_{mn}$-theorem and Gödel universal functions

Tags: logic, definition, recursion, computability

I was wondering what is the connection between a Gödel universal function (defined below) and the S-m-n theorem (stated below)? I'm almost sure there must be some connection, but I can't figure out the details. Probably there's a connection between the $s$ in the definition of a Gödel universal function and the program $s_n^m$ from the statement of the S-m-n theorem?

Some textbooks use exclusively Gödel universal functions without ever mentioning the S-m-n theorem; other textbooks don't talk about Gödel universal functions but use the S-m-n theorem in those places where the textbooks of the first type would have used Gödel universal functions (e.g. in $m$-reducing one set to another). That's the reason I think there should be a connection.

> A partial function $U: N\times N\to N$ is said to be a universal function for the class of computable functions of one argument if $U$ is computable and for any partial computable function of one argument $f$, there is $n\in N$ such that $U(n,x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in N$.

> A Gödel universal function is a universal function $U$ with the following property: if $V:N\times N\to N$ is any partial computable function, then there exists a total computable $s:N\to N$ such that for all $x,n\in N$ one has $V(n,x)=U(s(n),x)$.

> **S-m-n theorem**. There exists a natural number $s^m_n$ with the following property: for all natural $x,y_1,\dots,y_m,z_1,\
> \dots, z_n$, $$[\![ [\![s^m_n ]\!](x,y_1,\dots,y_m) ]\!](z_1,\dots,z_n)=[\![x]\!](y_1,\dots,y_m,z_1,\dots,z_n).$$
> (The notation $[\![ a ]\!](b)$, also written as $\varphi_a(b)$, stands for the result of the application of the program with number $a$ (in some computable (initailly fixed) enumeration of programs) to input $b$.)
>
> Also see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4021181/equivalence-of-two-versions-of-the-s-mn-theorem) for another statement of the S-m-n theorem.

Comment: The definition for Gödel universal function uses U without defining it.

Comment: @DanielV Thanks, fixed!

Comment: The first definition is just the Gödel version of defining a universal turing machine.  Not sure what the second is trying to get at, maybe trying to extend that idea to partial functions?  Anyway, the third definition is just saying that if $f(a, b)$ is computable, then so is any instance of that with $a$ hardcoded to whatever value you want.  For example, if $(x, y) \mapsto x+y$ is computable, then $x \mapsto x+1$ is also computable because that is just the first function with a value hardcoded into $y$.  I don't think there is any particular connection between them.

Comment: @DanielV The functions involved in the definition of universal, and Godel universal, functions should (with the exception of the translation function $s$) be partial rather than total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel free to correct/criticize/improve this answer.

---

Alright, I think I got it, at least most of it. I think the S-m-n theorem (for $m=n=1$) can be used to prove the existence of Gödel universal functions.

From what I understand, $U(x,y)$, $\varphi_x(y)$, $[\![ x ]\!](y)$ are various notations for the same thing, so I'll use them interchangeably.

Let $U$ be a universal function (with respect to some fixed computable enumeration of programs). Let $V: N\times N \to N$ be a partial computable function. Then there exists a program that computes it, say it has number $e$ in the fixed numbering mentioned above. So $$V(x,y)=[\![e]\!](x,y)$$ for all $x,y$. Let's construct the function $s$ from the definition of a Gödel universal function. In the case $m=n=1$, the S-m-n theorem says $$[\![ [\![s^1_1 ]\!](e,x) ]\!](y)=[\![e]\!](x,y).$$
Define $s:N\to N$ by $x\mapsto [\![s^1_1 ]\!](e,x) $. Then we have $$[\![s(x)]\!](y)=[\![e]\!](x,y) $$ or in other notation $$U(s(x),y)=V(x,y).$$

The only thing that's unclear to me is why this $s:x\mapsto [\![s^1_1 ]\!](e,x) $ is total.