# Equivalence of two versions of the $S_{mn}$-theorem

Tags: logic, recursion, computability

Here are two different versions of S-m-n theorem found in two differet sources. I was wondering if they're equivalent? The first talks about the existence of a number, the second talks about the existence of a function. I'm not sure if there's a way to construct one from the other and vice-versa and how such a construction would work. Any help would be appreciated.

> There exists a natural number $s^m_n$ with the following property: for all natural $x,y_1,\dots,y_m,z_1,\
> \dots, z_n$, $$[\![ [\![s^m_n ]\!](x,y_1,\dots,y_m) ]\!](z_1,\dots,z_n)=[\![x]\!](y_1,\dots,y_m,z_1,\dots,z_n).$$
> (The notation $[\![ a ]\!](b)$, also written as $\varphi_a(b)$, stands for the result of the application of the program with number $a$ (in some computable (initailly fixed) enumeration of programs) to input $b$.)

> There is a 1:1 computable function $s_n^m(x,y_1,\dots, y_m)$ such that for all $x,y_1,\dots,y_m, z_1,\dots, z_n,$ $$ [\![ s_n^m(x,y_1,\dots, y_m) ]\!] (z_1,\dots, z_n)=[\![ x]\!] (y_1,\dots, y_m,z_1,\dots, z_n)$$

Comment: The statement in parentheses in the first quote should give you the right clue about what's going on here. "1:1" in the second quote looks dubious to me. Can you please cite the sources.

Comment: @RobArthan Do you mean that $ [\![s^m_n ]\!] $ in the first quote is equal to the function $s_n^m$ in the second quote? It's not clear why it is computable. And if I have a function $s_n^m$ as in the second quote, I don't know how to get the corresponding number in the first quote. As for the sources, the source for the first quote is lecture notes coming from a local university; the source for the second quote is Soare's "Turing Computability: Theory and Applications".

Comment: $s_n^m$ in the first statement is a numeric code for the function $s_n^m$ in the second statement.