# Two versions of Kleene's recursion theorem - what's the relationship between them?

Tags: logic, recursion, computability

Below are two versions of Kleene's recursion theorem. How are they related? Are they equivalent? If not, does one of them (which one?) imply the other?

Note that both $U(n,x)$ and $\phi_n(x)$ is the result of application of program number $n$ to input $x$.

Version 1:

> If $H:N\to N$ is a total computable
> function and $U$ is a Godel universal computable function (defined
> [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4021150/connection-between-the-s-mn-theorem-and-g%C3%B6del-universal-functions)), then there is $n$ such that $U(n,x)=U(H(n),x)$ for all $x$ (i.e., there's a "program" that does the same thing before and after the application of $H$).

(The construction of the fixed point is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4043913/intuition-behind-the-construction-of-a-fixed-point-from-kleenes-fixed-point-the).)

Version 2:

> For every number $p$, there exists $q_0$ such that for all $x$, $$\phi_p(q_0,x)=\phi_{q_0}(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

The question of whether they're equivalent is a little imprecise since they're both true (whether one follows immediately from the other might depend on how the formalisms are developed), but I think both versions say essentially the same thing.

In version 2, we think of $p$ as encoding an interpreter that takes a program representation $q$ and runs it on input $x$ (using its own internal interpretation of $q$ as a program). The theorem states that for any such interpreter, there's a number $q_0$ that represents the same program in $p$'s "language" as it does in our "canonical language" of program numberings.

In version 1, given a Godel universal computable function $U$ (which we think of as a universal interpreter in the sense that for any interpreter $V$, we can computably translate programs from $V$'s language to $U$'s language), we can think of $H$ as the translation function for some arbitrary interpreter $V$. The theorem says that there's a number $n$ that represents the same program in $V$'s language that it does in the "universal" language of $U$.

Comment: I've always avoided dealing with "interpreters" because I don't understand what exactly this word means (I have no background in programming). Is there a way to rephrase your argument without using "interpreter"? Or is there an easy explanation of what "interpreter" is?

Comment: I think it's fairly easy to explain with an example: If I've written a Python program and saved it as `myscript.py`, and I want to run it on input `mydata.txt`, I issue the command `python myscript.py mydata.txt` on the command line. From the operating system's perspective, the only program is `python`, and the other two arguments are just data. But since `python` interprets its first argument as instructions to execute, we call it an interpreter.

Comment: The fixed point theorem in this case says that we can create a file `weirdprogram` such that the commands `python weirdprogram ...` and `weirdprogram ...` are functionally equivalent. This is surprising since the former command treats the contents of `weirdprogram` as Python code whereas the latter treats them as OS-level machine instructions, which have a non-text-based binary encoding. (Maybe less surprising if we consider that the behavior might just be to terminate on all inputs with an error message as output.)